# Can we load two xml files at a time dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

by using "AJAX" we can load our files like xml/json. But is there any possibility to load at a time two xml's using AJAX or get.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test.xml',
        type: "get",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

It can be done easily, **`jQuery`** even provides method that will help you done this in a heartbeat. Basically all you need is to chain several ajax calls and process then with **`$.when`** when they are done.

### Example

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qNJS8/

In this example you can see 3 distinct calls using **`$.ajax`** function. Also a warning, because **`jsFiddle`** don't support ajax calls fetching xml all data retrieved are dummy data, you will only need to replace it wit a proper **`URL`**.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){  
    // Multiple Ajax Requests 
    $.when( 
        parseXML({xml: "<cars><car><name>TOYOTA</name><country>JAPAN</country><pic>http://1call.ms/Websites/schwartz2012/images/toyota-rav4.jpg</pic><description>Toyota has announced that it will recall a total of 778,000 units that may have been manufactured with improperly-tightened nuts on the rear suspension.</description></car></cars>"}) , 
        parseXML({xml: "<cars><car><name>RENAULT</name><country>FRANCE</country><pic>http://cdn2.carsdata.net/thumb/182x105/pics/Renault/renault-sandero-16-stepway-01.jpg</pic><description>Renault Sandero 16 Stepway - this car is manufactured by renault. Renault Sandero 16 Stepway - Get car information and expert advice from CarsData.</description></car></cars>"}) , 
        parseXML({xml: "<cars><car><name>AUDI</name><country>GERMANY</country><pic>http://img2.netcarshow.com/Audi-RS6_Avant_2014_800x600_wallpaper_06.jpg</pic><description>The new Audi RS6 Avant unites 412 kW (560 hp) of power and 700 Nm (516.29 lb-ft) of torque with unrestricted practicality for everyday use and leisure.</description></car></cars>"})
    ).done(
        function(data1, data2, data3)
        {
            var allData = [].concat(data1).concat(data2).concat(data3);
            $(allData).find("car").each(function(){
                $('#cars-data').append('<li><a href="#cars"><img src="' + $(this).find('pic').text() + '" title="sample" height="100%" width="100%"/><h3>Car type:<span> '+ $(this).find('name').text() +'</span></h3><p>' + $(this).find('description').text() + '</p></a></li>'); 
            })
            $('#cars-data').listview('refresh');            
        }
    ).fail(
        function()
        {
            alert('Fail');  
        }
    );

    function parseXML(data)
    {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/echo/xml/",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {}
        });
    }   
});
```

### Explanation

Basically to understand this you only need to understand method **`$.when`**. It accepts multiple functions a parameters and provide **`done`** and `fail` callback. If we are reading same kind of data we can use **`concat`** function to merge everything together. After that do whatever you want with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just launch two ajax requests:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.xml',
    type: "get",
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("failure");
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'test2.xml',
    type: "get",
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

See question [jQuery: Making simultaneous ajax requests, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898190/jquery-making-simultaneous-ajax-requests-is-it-possible) if you wants more information

Extract of answers :

" You want asynchronous (which is the default). The browser limits you to two requests at any given time. This is part of the HTTP specification. (HTTP 1.1 specification, section 8.1.4) "