# Multiple asynchronous request limit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have created  multiple asynchronous request with jquery like this:

```
       $.when(
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city_1, 
                type: "GET", 
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data) {
                    data_1 = data;
                }
            }),
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city_2, 
                type: "GET", 
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data) {
                    data_2 = data;
                }
            }),
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city_3, 
                type: "GET", 
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data) {
                    data_3 = data;
                }
            }),
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city_4, 
                type: "GET", 
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data) {
                    data_4 = data;
                }
            }),
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city_5, 
                type: "GET", 
                data: window.location.search, 
                dataType: "json", 
                success: function(data) {
                    data_5 = data;
                }
            })
        ).then(function() {
           //other code
        });
```

I expected into the console to view all request start at the same time but isn't right.

This is my net screenshot from firebug and you can see that the last request start only when previous finished. Why? Is there a limit of asynchronous request?

[image]

The image is little but you can view the last two request that aren't asynchronous!
The first line isn't an asynchronous request but it was into the screenshot

I need to have all request start at the same time

Comment: In short, it depends on your severside implementation.

Comment: ok but in what depends serverside?

Comment: For starters, what language are you using?

Comment: Hmm I was hoping for .NET since I have a solution there. But it seems like a common problem for concurrent ajax requests in php is the session being blocked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686572/two-simultaneous-ajax-requests-wont-run-in-parallel

Comment: uhm I don't know if is the problem because I'm using codeIgniter and this function are very big but not used to write session only to return big array of data

Comment: if I create a domain of second or third level I can escape this problem? @Johan

Comment: Sorry was AFK for while. If you don't want to get involved with sessions, you could split up the php files and let each file handle its own task. That way you could send multiple requests and handle them in paralell. Not the best solution, but an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this SO: [jQuery: Making simultaneous ajax requests, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898190/jquery-making-simultaneous-ajax-requests-is-it-possible)

> The browser limits you to two requests at any given time. This is part
>   of the HTTP specification. (HTTP 1.1 specification, section 8.1.4)

Comment: is there any way to increase or some methods to remove this problem?

Comment: Nope. It's up to the browser really but the latest browsers don't care: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. — It's a feature.

Depending on the browser, there are limits on simultaneous AJAX connections per domain and probably various methods as well. The best way to get over this is to combine the data responses into as few files as possible.

Comment: isn't possible to combine this different methods

Comment: Then you're out of luck. I'm sorry.